# Multiple Forms on Same Page that Sends Unique HTML Emails and Success/Error Message for Each Form

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, html-email

I've been working on trying to figure out how to validate two forms on same page that are posted to self. Each form should return either success of error messages based on input values that should be relative to each form.  In other words should the user post to the "email-form" a success or error message should appear after submission attached to that form without affecting the "call-form" and vice versa. I've been able validate and send  HTML email successfully, however the success and error messages do not show on the client side.  This could be a minor fix such as an error in the code or positioning. I could really use some help and clear explanation from you PHP experts out there please and thank you!

The following is HTML with unique identifiers for each form and related inputs.  Simple PHP validation is used and data is sent to email.

```
 <?php 
    $name1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name1']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); 

    if(isset($_POST['email-submit']) { 
        if($name1 != "") { 
            $name1 = filter_var($name1, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            if($name1 == "") { 
                $errors1 = "Please enter your name";
            } 
        else { 
            $errors1 = "provide a name";
        }       
        if($email != "") { 
            $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
                $errors1 = "Please enter a valid email";
            }
        } else { 
            $errors1 = "Please enter a email";
        }
        if(!errors1) {
          $to = "First Name <name@example.com>";
          $subject = "Email Form Submission"; 
          $headers = "From: " . $to . "\r\n\";
          $headers. = "Reply-To: " . $email . "\r\n\";
          $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
          $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
          $message = "<html><body>";
          $message .= "<p>You've recieved a new message from {$name1}!</p>";
          $message .= "<p>please email {$name1} at {$email} ASAP!</p>";
          $message .= "</body></html>";

          mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
          echo $success1 = "<span class='success'>Thank you for your submission</span>";
        } else { 
            echo $errors1 = "<span class='errors'></span>";
        }   
    }
?>  
<form name='email-form' method='post' action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]);?>'>
    <input type='text' name='name1' id='name1' value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name1']);?>'>
    <input type='email' name='email' id='email' value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);?>'>
    <div><?php echo $errors1;?></div> 
    <div><?php echo $success1;?></div> 
    <input type='submit' name='email-submit' id='email-submit'>
</form> 
<?php 
    $name2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name2']);
    $tel = htmlspecialchars($_POST['tel']); 

    if(isset($_POST['email-submit']) { 
        if($name2 != "") { 
            $name2 = filter_var($name2, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            if($name2 == "") { 
                $errors2 = "Please enter your name";
            } 
        else { 
            $errors2 = "provide a name";
        }    
        if($tel != "") { 
            $errors2 = "please provide a valid phone number";
        } else { 
            $errors2 = "please provide a phone number";
        } 
        if(!errors2) {
          $to = "firstName lastName <name@example.com>";
          $subject = "Email Form Submission"; 
          $headers = "From: " . $to . "\r\n\";
          $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email . "\r\n\";
          $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
          $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
          $message = "<html><body>";
          $message .= "<p>You've recieved a new message from {$name2}!</p>";
          $message .= "<p>please call {$name2} at {$tel} ASAP!</p>";
          $message .= "</body></html>";

          mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
          echo $success2 = "<span class='success'>Thank you for your submission</span>";
        } else { 
            echo $error2 = "<span class='errors'></span>";
        }  
    }
?>
<form name='call-form' method='post' action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]);?>'>
    <input type='text' name='name2' id='name2' value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name2']);?>'>
    <input type='tel' name='tel' id='tel' value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['tel']);?>'>
    <div><?php echo $errors2; ?></div>
    <div><?php echo $success2;?></div> 
    <input type='submit' name='call-submit' id='call-submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: You are echoing you error message -> Line#4 `<div><?php echo $errors1;?></div> ` before you are creating/setting the error message -> Line#16 `$errors1 = "Please enter your name";` / etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sean. How would you propose that I best make this change? I moved the entire PHP script from below each form to above the form... Just tested it out in server and it's still not working. Is there a better way to edit code?

Comment: If you want to process a form on the same page, you need to include the php code above the form, so that all your variables are set before trying to use them. If you have made changes to your code, update your question with the changes you have tried. It will be easier to help you knowing what you currently have/tried.

Comment: I've updated code based on your feedback, not sure if my edits were what you meant. Also, now the forms are not validating and sending success/error messages.